# MongoDB UpdateMany Method

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

how can i use the update Many Method inside my code?. Right now this code will insert the data over and over inside the table, i need to make it so it will update the old data and add new data if new data is available in the third party api. I'm new to MongoDB any help will be much appreciate it! thanks.

```
cron.schedule('0 0 * * *', async () => {

    const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
        id: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        status: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
    
    });
    
    const Post = mongoose.model('players', postSchema);
    
    async function getPosts() {
        const getPlayers = await fetch("http://localhost:3008/api/players");
        const response = await getPlayers.json();
        for( let i = 0;i < response.players.length; i++){
    
    const post = new Post({
        id: response.players[i]['id'],
        name: response.players[i]['name'],
        status: response.players[i]['status'],
    });
    post.save();
    
    
        }
    
    }
    console.log("Task submitted successfully")
    await getPosts();
});
```

what i was thinking

```
    const post = await Post.updateMany({
        id: response.players[i]['id'],
        name: response.players[i]['name'],
        status: response.players[i]['status'],
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `bulkWrite` and inside `bulkWrite` you can write `updateOne` operation with the `upsert` flag set to `true`

You can construct an array of operations as follows

```
let operations = [];

for (let player of players) {
  operations.push({
    updateOne: {
      filter: { id: player.id },
      update: { $set: { name: player.name } },
      upsert: true,
    }
  })
}
```

And finally you can make a call to `bulkWrite`. [Please read the documentation for the operations above](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#behavior)

Comment: thanks for your answer, im going to try it, besides this i was thinking on setting up a daily backup at midnight and after midnight delete the database and right after delete the database insert new information, would that work ?